# Passing a function to an argument in Scala

Tags: function, scala, arguments, chaining

Is there any way to do something like `argument.<keyword>(function)` in Scala?

For example:

`[1,2,3].supply(myFunc)` yielding `6` if myFunc were the summation function.

It just seems easier to chain functions if I were able to do this, instead of calculating something and 'wrapping it' into an argument for a function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define it yourself if you want. It's frequently called the "pipe operator":

```
class AnyWrapper[A](wrapped: A) {
  def |>[B](f: A => B) = f(wrapped)
}
implicit def extendAny[A](wrapped: A): AnyWrapper[A] = new AnyWrapper(wrapped)
```

Then:

```
def plus1(i: Int) = i + 1
val fortyTwo = 41 |> plus1
```

Comment: `A <: Any` doesn't really restrict things much, does it?

Comment: @RexKerr Uh, I really don't know why I thought it was worth adding! I've removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
val sum = { (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b }

List(1, 2, 3).reduceLeft(sum)
```

Comment: That's specific to the summation function.  I want something like `<arbitrary arg>.appliedTo(<arbitrary fn>)`, which would have the same effect as `<arbitrary fn>.(<arbitrary arg>)`.  Is there a keyword that functions the same as `appliedTo`?